# my html form isnt sending to an email

Tags: javascript, html, forms, contact-form

i am making a form for people to check in via an app but when i submit the form it will not send to my email address the page just refreshes can someone please help i have put the code below

```
 <form action="mailto:myemail@email.com" method="post">    
     name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="name" label="name"><br>


     date:<br> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var hh = today.getHours();
    var mn = today.getMinutes();
    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
    if(hh<10) {
        hh='0'+hh
    }
    if(mn<10) {
        mn='0'+mn                                                               
    }
    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;  
    var now = " " + hh+':'+mn;
    document.write(today);
    document.write(now);
    </script>             <br>


    location:<br>
           <input type="text" name="location" label="location"><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">     

     </form>
```

Comment: Try to minimize your code to find out where the issue resides.

Comment: all i want it to do is automatically send to my email address when i press submit @SaeX

Answer (score 0):

'mailto:' does not send emails.  The code posted above will attempt to open the users default mail client with a pre-formatted message, but the user will need to review the message and click 'send'.  This is probably not what you want.

The best solution would be to post the form to a url in your app and send the email in the server-side code.